# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn databind to control outside?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Well i have a control thats placed in a usercontrol and it exposes a ICommand with a DepenceyPropety(ShowCommand), 
and then i have a datagrid (wpf toolkit) with a few columns and one of them has a delete button

```
<Custom:DataGrid Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Todos}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
      <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=ConfirmDeleteDialog, Path=ShowCommand}" 
                            Content="Delete" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
</Custom:DataGrid>
<local:ConfirmationDialog x:Name="ConfirmDeleteDialog" 
                          Title="Confirm delete!" 
                          d:LayoutOverrides="Width" 
                          Message="Are you sure that you want to delete the selected todo?" 
                          YesCommand="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
```

and as im in a DataTemplate it does not find the element, and i can't combine ElementName and Relative source so how would i define a binding that can access an element declared outside the datatemplate?

The command im trying to bind to is located on ConfirmationDialog.YesCommand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved it this way i changed my dialog to a to inherit from ContentControl instead of Control and added a content holder in it..

after that i moved the dialog so it wrapped the whole control, after that i added a routed event that i can listen to and that worked like a charm.